# What kind of method approach is this?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to disable the editing but not highlighting of all cells in my JTable.

I have the following example from a website and it works as expected:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, new String[]{"First header", "Second header", "Third Header"});

JTable table = new JTable(model) 
{ 
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
};
```

What happens right after the instantiation of the **table** variable?

Am I some kind of overriding the instance method **isCellEditable**?

Comment: This is an instance of an **anonymous class**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). It is an instantiation of a class that extends `JTable` and overrides its `isCellEditable` method.

Answer (score 1):

It's creating an anonymous class derived from `JTable`.

In the code:

```
public ExistingClass x = new ExistingClass { ... }
```

this actually creates a class derived from `ExistingClass`. It's a concise means of providing a single derived instance. In your above example it's done simply to override one method.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating an [Anonymous Class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm):

> An anonymous class is a local class without a name. An anonymous class
> is defined and instantiated in a single succinct expression using the
> new operator.

And yes, you are overriding a method here.